# Append Error in Python?

Tags: python, append, traceback

I'm coding using a book, and when I have any list like this:
`cool_peps = ('me, louis, linus')`and try to append something to it, I get the following error:

```
cool_peps = ('me, louis, linus')
cool_peps.append('sasha')
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#4>", line 1, in <module>
cool_peps.append('sasha')
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'append'
```

What does this mean and how can I fix it?
Thank you very much!

Comment: `cool_peps = ['me', 'louis', 'linus']` make it a list.

Comment: Wow thanks so much to everyone, I never thought I'll get feedback that fast.  I got it now. And to Christian König, I know that this is very basic - I said that I am new to programming. It is difficult for me to focus on details as I want to learn and understand as quickly as possible. Thank you for your answer though.

Answer (score 1):

If you take a look at `cool_peps` you will see that it is a string, not the tuple/list that you might have thought:

```
>>> cool_peps = ('me, louis, linus')
>>> cool_peps
'me, louis, linus'
>>> type(cool_peps)
<class 'str'>
```

> What does this mean and how can I fix it?

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'append'
```

`str` objects do not have an append method/, so you see the error above.

What you probably want is a *list*:

```
>>> cool_peps = ['me, louis, linus']
>>> cool_peps
['me, louis, linus']
>>> cool_peps.append('sasha')
>>> cool_peps
['me, louis, linus', 'sasha']
```

If you do want to convert the list to a string you can use `str.join()`:

```
>>> ', '.join(cool_peps)
'me, louis, linus, sasha'
```

or use `print()`:

```
>>> print(*cool_peps, sep=', ')
me, louis, linus, sasha
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a list, you have a string.

```
>>> cool_peps = ('me, louis, linus')
>>> type(cool_peps)
<class 'str'>
>>> print(cool_peps)
me, louis, linus
```

To get a list, use this:

```
>>> cool_peps_list = ['me', 'louis', 'linus']
>>> type(cool_peps_list)
<class 'list'>
>>> print(cool_peps_list)
['me', 'louis', 'linus']

>>> cool_peps_list.append('sasha')
>>> print(cool_peps_list)
['me', 'louis', 'linus', 'sasha']
```

Since this is very basic, please go back to the book and pay attention to the details.

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems with your first line.  The three names in parenthesis are all part of the same string.  First, you need to split them into 3 separate strings.

```
cool_peps = ['me', 'louis, 'linus']
```

Second, notice that I also changed the parenthesis to brackets.  Brackets indicate a list, which you can `append` to.  Parenthesis indicates a tuple, which cannot be changed.

Answer (score 0):

For string concentration, you can use `+`:

```
>>> x = 'me, louis, linus'
>>> type(x)
<class 'str'>
>>> x += ', sasha'
>>> print(x)
me, louis, linus, sasha
>>>
```

Append works for lists:

```
>>> x = ['me, louis, linus']
>>> type(x)
<class 'list'>
>>> x.append('sasha')
>>> print(x)
['me, louis, linus', 'sasha']
>>>
```

To convert the list to a string, there is the join() function:

```
>>> newStr = ' '.join(x)
>>> print(newStr)
me, louis, linus sasha
>>> type(newStr)
<class 'str'>
```

Answer (score -1):

Let me know one thing **cool_peps = ('me, louis, linus')** is it a list?? I don't think so.

Coming to original code is

**cool_peps = ['me','louis','linus']**

**cool_peps.append('sasha')**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8wBcE.png)